# PSQL: Weird issue while summing - getting multiplied by number of rows

Tags: psql

Here's the `tv_1` table:

```
id  | fig
-------------
111 | 500
222 | 200
111 | 300
111 | 200
111 | 300
```

Here's `tv_2`:

```
id  | test
-------------
111 | 50
111 | 70
111 | 40
```

When I do this query:

```
SELECT sum(tv_1.fig), tv_2.id
FROM tv_1
JOIN tv_2 ON tv_1.id = tv_2.id
WHERE tv_1.id = 111
GROUP BY tv_2.id
```

I get:

```
sum  | id
-------------
3900 | 111
```

But I need to get:

```
sum  | id
-------------
1300 | 111
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

```
SELECT SUM(tv_1.fig), v.id
FROM tv_1
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT tv_2.id FROM tv_2) v ON v.id = tv_1.id
WHERE tv_1.id = 111
GROUP BY v.id
```

This gave me:

```
sum  | id
-------------
1300 | 111
```